# Is it possible to read gzip file directly with jq?

Tags: gzip, jq

I'm reading huge json files with `jq`, something like:

```
jq -r '[.a, .b, .time] | @tsv' file.txt
```

those files are coming as `gz` files and I spend each day 20 minutes just to `gunzip` them.
I was wondering is it possible to read the files with `jq` directly from the `gz` format? and if so, will it faster overall or will it slow down my process?

Comment: You can pipe the output of `gunzip`, directly to `jq` which can stream it.

Comment: Can you provide the source JSON? does it contain only those fields `a,b,time` or more ?

Comment: only those, something like:`{"a": "a", "b": "a", "time": "20210210T10:10:00"}` multiple times in a file

Comment: Can you try `gunzip -c filename.gz | jq -r -nc --stream '[inputs|select(length==2)|.[1]]|@tsv'`. Even the `select(length==2)` can be omitted, if there are no other records

Comment: @Inian, That outputs one very long record instead of one for each JSON text as the original does.

Comment: some systems have `zcat` (which just wraps gunzip) for streaming the contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it takes 20 minutes to unzip, it's going to take 20 minutes to unzip whether the library is used by `gunzip` or by `jq`.

But, you could avoid writing the unzipped file to disk and the time related to that. This would be achieved by using `gunzip -c`.

```sh
gunzip -c file.gz | jq -r '[ .a, .b, .time ] | @tsv' >file.tsv
```

---

To be clear, the above uses minimal memory. Not one of the three files (compressed, decompressed or TSV) is found in memory in its entirety at any time.

The following demonstrates the streaming nature of `jq`:

```
$ (
   j='{"a": "a", "b": "a", "time": "20210210T10:10:00"}'
   printf '%s\n' "$j"
   printf '%s\n' "$j"
   sleep 4
   printf '%s\n' "$j"
) | jq -r '[ .a, .b, .time, now ] | @tsv'
a       a       20210210T10:10:00       1620305187.460741
a       a       20210210T10:10:00       1620305187.460791
[4 second pause]
a       a       20210210T10:10:00       1620305191.459734
```

The first two records are emitted without delay, and the third is emitted after 4 seconds. This is reflected by the timestamps.

Comment: Why not streaming? - _..reading huge json.._

Comment: @Inian, That does stream. Maybe you mean `--stream`? That would be silly considering the OP said each JSON text is of the form `{"a": "a", "b": "a", "time": "20210210T10:10:00"}`.

Comment: @Inian, A demo of `jq`'s streaming nature has been added to my answer.

Comment: It streams because you are reading a stream of JSON objects rather than a single JSON value. If the input is, say, one huge JSON array, `--stream` may be necessary to avoid reading the entire value into memory at once.

Comment: @chepner, Yes, I didn't mean to imply `jq` always streams. My answer strictly covers the OP's data (as implied by my first comment).